# System.StackOverflowException was unhandled - C#, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-overflow

How to fix it.
It look like this page is dedicated to that kind of error.

[image]

Comment: This site is _named after_ Stack Overflow exceptions; it isn't dedicated to them.

Comment: This site does have answers for a few other questions as well :)

Comment: first laugh of the day - thanks!

Comment: Oh irony - thou art hilarious.  =)

Comment: Sadly, a stack overflow is becoming a tricky error to find information on using Google.

Comment: `if InvokeRequired then an Invoke is required`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your function is calling itself forever.
You need to make it stop calling itself.

In this case, you need to `Invoke` it to the UI thread instead of simply calling itself again:

```
Invoke(new Action(UpdateAdvert));
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `InvokeRequired` is `true`. This causes unbounded recursion. There's nothing that will change it to false. Perhaps invoking would fix it?